# How to install the i386 version of R on ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, 32-bit, i386

How to install the i386 version of R on ubuntu?

I already have the x64 version installed on the server, but I need the 32-bit version to use a library that is on the same version.

Comment: I don't know and can't research it now but maybe there is some workaround using multiarch (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) . Just an idea.

Comment: @lebatsnok I have only one library in the R application that is on i386 (32-bit) version, the R and Ubuntu are on the 64-bit version, do not know how to multiarch can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend installing VirtualBox, and running a 32 bit Ubuntu version in that. This is much more straightforward than trying to run 32 bit software on a 64 bit OS. When you have the 32 bit OS installed, you can simply add [this repository](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) to your `sources.list`, and install the binary version of R.

Comment: Install a virtual machine just to compile a library of application? Be the best alternative?

Comment: The problem is that you need to run the 32 bit version of R to use a 32 bit version of a library. For that, you might need 32 bit versions of certain libraries that R needs, etc, etc. In addition, the 32 bit libraries can pollute your installation if you are not careful. Installing a separate OS in a VM provides a relatively straightforward solution, that separates the 32 bit stuff from the 64 bit.